# how can i access nested array from mongoDB collection using spring boot?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, nested

I am writing a credit card management system. This is the DB for the project (each user can have many cards and each card can have many transactions)

DB code sample:

```
{
    "_id": 1,
    "name": "Jawad",
    "lastname": "Zakhour",
    "username": "jwdzkh",
    "password": "pass123",
    "cards": [{
        "cardnumber": "1234-5678-9123-4567",
        "cardholdername": "yolla kazan",
        "expirationdate": "05/09/2021",
        "cvv": "256",
        "type": "Credit",
        "creditlimit": "3500",
        "transactions": [{
            "date": "03/06/2020",
            "amount": 750,
            "receiptNo": "EAC-15-123-45678"
        }, {
            "date": "06/08/2020",
            "amount": 320,
            "receiptNo": "THY-18-568-5866"
        }]
    }, {
        "cardnumber": "4589-3256-7841-9655",
        "cardholdername": "nabil dagher",
        "expirationdate": "06/07/2022",
        "cvv": "365",
        "type": "Debit",
        "balance": "5200",
        "transactions": [{
            "date": "09/11/2019",
            "amount": 90,
            "receiptNo": "TYH-35-163-5896"
        }, {
            "date": "10/10/2020",
            "amount": 120,
            "receiptNo": "NJU-85-586-4287"
        }]
    }, {
        "cardnumber": "8976-3154-3187-3659",
        "cardholdername": "jawad zakhour",
        "expirationdate": "06/07/2022",
        "cvv": "365",
        "type": "Debit",
        "balance": "12000",
        "transactions": [{
            "date": "01/02/2018",
            "amount": 14,
            "receiptNo": "DFG-58-348-9863"
        }, {
            "date": "04/12/2019",
            "amount": 550,
            "receiptNo": "FGH-46-008-3478"
        }]
    }]
}
```

on java spring boot I have three models *User*, *Card*, *Transaction*.

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@Document(collection = "Vault")
public class Card {
    
    private String cardnumber;
    private String cardholdername;
    private String expirationdate;
    private String cvv;
    private String type;
    private String creditlimit;
    private String balance;
    private List<Transaction> transactions;

}

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@Document(collection = "Vault")
public class User {

    @Id
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String lastname;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private List<Card> cards;

}

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Transaction {

    private String date;
    private int amount;
    private String receiptNo;

}
```

and also I have created 2 repositories CardsRepository and UserRepository

How can I Return all cards of a specific user?

now i want to get all the transactions for a specific card how is that possible?
since every card has a list it should be possible..

Comment: `val cards = userRepository.findById(id).map(User::getCards).orElseThrow(..)`

Comment: Thank you!! I will try it. Is there any way i can do it using a CardRepository extends MongoRepository<Card,String>?

Comment: Man you’re the best it worked !

Comment: @夢のの夢 i need help again...
now i want to retrieve all Transactions of a specific card
same concept.. but it's not working.
any idea?

Comment: @夢のの夢
val crd = repository.findByUsername(username).map(User::getCards).map(Card::getTransactions);
this wont wok...

Comment: @夢のの夢 i updated my question.. please i need your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get transactions of a specific card, just use `filter(<some_predicate>)`. For example,

```
val user = userRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> UserNotFoundException(id));
val transactions = user.getCards()
        .stream()
        .filter(card -> card.getCardNumber().equals("1111.."))
        .findFirst()
        .map(Card::getTransactions)
        .orElseGet(Collections::emptyList);
```

Here, if a specific card that matches the predicate that `cardNumber` equals some input, it will be passed on to the next operation in the stream pipeline and `findFirst()` returns the first occurrence of such card.

Edit with request:

```
@GetMapping("/users/{username}/cards/{cardnumber}/transactions")    
public List<Transaction> getTransactionByCardnumber(@PathVariable String username, @PathVariable String cardnumber) {
    val user = userRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> UserNotFoundException(id));
    val transactions = user.getCards()
            .stream()
            .filter(card -> card.getCardnumber().equals(cardnumber))
            .findFirst()
            .map(Card::getTransactions)
            .orElseGet(Collections::emptyList);
}
```

Comment: `@GetMapping("/getTransaction")
 public Optional<Transaction> getTransactionByCardnumber()
 {
  val transactions = repository.findById(1)
    .map(User::getCards)
    .filter(card -> card.getCardNumber.equals("1234-4567-2345-3455")
    .findFirst().map(Card::getTransactions)
    .orElse(Collections::emptyList));
  
  return transactions;
 }`


i tried it like that i need it in an api I'm getting error on
getCardNumber : getCardNumber cannot be resolved or is not a field
return transaction : Type mismatch: cannot convert from Optional<List<Card>> to Optional<Transaction>
@夢のの夢

Comment: I typed that on a fly. should be getCardNumber()

Comment: Okay thank you so much i really appreciate your help.

Comment: I tried it and its still not working
am i missing something?
and the return statement has a error too (Type mismatch: cannot convert from Optional<List<Card>> to Optional<Transaction>)

Comment: I didn't test the previous code and the issue you mentioned was caused by `.filter()` was expecting a stream of card `Stream<Card>` instead of `Optional<List<Card>>` from `User::getCards`

Comment: It still won't work :/:/ i literally tried everything.
it worked for the list of cards for a specific user 
why wouldn't it work for a list of transactions for a specific card...
any idea?
sorry for asking too much but this is the last step of my project

Comment: the GetCards() : The method getCards() is undefined for the type Optional<User>

Comment: You need a terminating operator to unwrap the `Optional<User>`, so either throw it (like 
what I did) or do `orElse(defaultUser)`

Comment: can i ask you another question?
`[
    [
        {
            "date": "03/06/2020",
            "amount": 750,
            "receiptNo": "EAC-15-123-45678"
        },
        {
            "date": "06/08/2020",
            "amount": 320,
            "receiptNo": "THY-18-568-5866"
        }
    ]
]`
this is the result after i tried the code you gave me and thats what i want.
but there is one problem...
as you can see there is two additional brackets in the response.
its like the transactions are still in some sort of array.
is there anyway to return only the transactions..

Comment: `@GetMapping("/getTransaction/{username}/{cardnumber}")
 public Stream<List<Transaction>> getTransactionByCardnumber(@PathVariable String username, @PathVariable String cardnumber)
 {
  val user = repository.findByUsername(username).orElse(null);
  val transactions = user.getCards().stream().filter(card -> card.getCardnumber().equals(cardnumber)).map(Card::getTransactions);
  return transactions;
 }`
thats the function i finally used

Comment: you are returning `Stream<List<Transaction>>` therefore it `List<Transaction>` became nested. I updated my answer. and pls accept the answer if helpful.

Comment: Sure all your answers were helpful.. Thank you
(just i had some errors withe the orElseThrow(() -> UserNotFoundException(id)) and .orElseGet(Collections::emptyList))
but i worked my way around them.
thanks again !

Comment: You are very welcome. There are reasons why I did `orElseThrow` and `orElseGet`. I saw you did `orElse(null)`, in such case you need the handle  when `User` is null, hence null check, a nicer approach would just throw a RuntimeException in which you give message like `User '123' is not found`. As for `orElseGet(Collections::emptyList)`, You should provide a default value of empty list if no transactions is found given the cardNumber, which is again, to eliminate null, and thus preventing consumer of that api from getting potential `null` in their response.